# how to get Id of documents in Firestore using useCollectionData hook

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

```
const messagesRef = collection(db, 'messages')
const q = query(messagesRef, orderBy('createdAt'), limit(25))
const [messages, loading] = useCollectionData(q)
// messages print fields of documents without id
```

Need to get Id of documents, I guess there's a way to pass options in that hook but dk how.

If there's no way to get Id using that hook then what's the option?

Comment: Please make some kind of attempt at solving your problem before posting here. Did you read the docs? What have you tried so far? Why didn't your attempts work, etc. Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Well, I changed hook to useCollection

```
const [messages, loading] = useCollection(q)
```

This solved a problem.
`useCollectionData` only returns fields of documents, while `useCollection` returns `snapshot` with every document and id.